# VBS not waiting for .Run command to finish

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I have a code that will automatically open the Personalization window, change the theme to Windows 7 Basic, and then close the window. The problem is, the window does not close after the run command is completed. The code I'm using is this:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme""",1,true

WshShell.AppActivate("Desktop Properties") 
WshShell.Sendkeys "%FC"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{F4}"
```

Now, with the "true" statement at the end, isn't it supposed to basically wait for this command to complete, and THEN it will move on? Because if I remove the "true" statement as well as the "1" at the end, and instead add in a timer such as:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme"""


Wscript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.AppActivate("Desktop Properties") 
WshShell.Sendkeys "%FC"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{F4}"
```

Only here it will wait for the task to complete, and then close the window. What am I doing wrong! Also, can someone explain exactly what the "%FC" and "{F4}" do? I know one of them closes the window but I'm having trouble finding exactly what they mean. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: If you set the 3rd parameter of the `Run` method to `True` the method will only return after `rundll32.exe` terminates, which renders the rest of your script pointless. You need to identify a condition that indicates that your task has completed, and check for that condition before continuing.

Comment: I see your point, but how can you terminate it? Because all it does is change the theme to a certain file, so it's basically clicking a file and waiting for it to load. I did however find that this works: `Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme""",1,true

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "taskkill /fi ""WINDOWTITLE eq Personalization""", 0, true`

Comment: Why would that work? Because it waits for the `rundll32` to finish and then the window closes RIGHT after it's complete. I'm not sure.

Comment: %FC translates to hitting the keys Alt F C. % is the character for Alt. F and C represent the shortcuts for File and Close in that particular window. Curly braces are for SendKeys code in your example its for the F4 key.

`WshShell.Sendkeys "%FC"`
`WshShell.Sendkeys "{F4}"`

More reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the reply. I should have said after finding out but I completely forgot but I did in fact find that out. Thank you though! Do you have any idea by the way about my initial question? Just wondering. If not, no problem and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I wish i knew the real reason for it but it seems that the script is working by design. RunDll32.exe must be passing off processing to another process which is why the script appears to continue without waiting. I updated the script to prove what was happening

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

msgbox (IsProcessRunning("rundll32.exe"))
WshShell.Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme""",1,true
msgbox (IsProcessRunning("rundll32.exe"))
WshShell.AppActivate("Desktop Properties") 
WshShell.Sendkeys "%FC"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{F4}"

Function IsProcessRunning(pProcessName)
    ' Function will do a WMI query to determine if a the process pProcessName is currently
    ' running on the local computer. Returns True if detected. 
    Dim objWMIService
    Dim strWMIQuery

    strWMIQuery = "Select * From Win32_Process Where name Like '" & pProcessName & "'"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2") 

    ' Run The query against the WMI for the local machine
    If (objWMIService.ExecQuery(strWMIQuery).Count > 0) Then
        IsProcessRunning = True
    Else
        IsProcessRunning = False
    End If
End Function
```

I added a function that checks if a process is running. Once before your command to prove it is not already running. After the rundll32.exe call to also prove it is still not running. While this might seem redundant to show the second False message box will appear before the proccessing of the theme change is complete.

Snippet from an old MS KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787

> How Rundll Works
>
> Rundll performs the following steps:
>   1. It parses the command line.
>   2. It loads the specified DLL via LoadLibrary().
>   3. It obtains the address of the  function via GetProcAddress().
>   4. It calls the  function, passing the command line tail which is the .
>   5. When the  function returns, Rundll.exe unloads the DLL and exits.

Hopefully someone can embellish this.

Comment: This helps so much in understanding why it works the way it does. I can't upvote your post unfortunately, but thank you for posting this, it really clarifies a lot. I will keep looking into this.