# VBS Run command without opening explorer window

Tags: vbscript

The following code is used to change my Windows theme:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sLocalAppDataPath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%localappdata%")

WshShell.Exec "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""" & sLocalAppDataPath & "\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\Custom.theme"""
```

After it is finished running, the Peronalization window stays open. Is it possible to run a file without even opening the window to begin with? I know how to close it using sendkeys, but I don't want to do this. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx  lists arguments that can be used

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740285/vbs-not-waiting-for-run-command-to-finish/24744746#24744746 It tries to show that you cant wait for rundll32.exe to finish processing with InitWindowStyle. The OP used a Sleep with SendKeys. @Sorceri is what you were trying to lead OP to?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done without sending keystrokes or using autoit or something like that.
Take a look at http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-change-a-windows-theme-from-the-command-prompt/
Haven't tried ik but looks promissing.
Keep us informed.

Succes !

Comment: Thanks for the info, I really thought it would be possible it seems so simple! But thank you regardless :)

Comment: You can control any explorer window (also close without sending keystrokes) via IWebBrowser instance. [Here is an example.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25249296/2165759)

Comment: @omegastripes the point is not that a window can't be closed -he says he can do that btw - but that the windows opens at all, the problem is that microsoft dit not include that possibility in an API, I suppose that in C and with the right knowledge you can build something like the utility i pointed to
You should better read the question and answer before voting someone down

Comment: Oh my bad! Anyway objection sustained.